# The character reference must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: xml, jsf, facelets

I have an JSF 2.2 Page like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY times "&#00D7;"> 
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<head>
```

but get an excpetion

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 3] Zeichenreferenz muss mit dem Begrenzungszeichen ";" enden.
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:444)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:427)
```

The file is saved in UTF-8

whats wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified a hexadecimal value using the decimal notation. The XML parser got confused when it encountered the `D` while expecting a `;`.

Hexadecimal entity notation needs a `x` prefix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY times "&#xD7;">
]>
```

Otherwise, use the decimal notation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY times "&#215;">
]>
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode Character 'MULTIPLICATION SIGN' (U+00D7)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm) - check 2nd table "Encodings"